# swift 3 trigger on container view contents update

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I have a view controller containing a container view.  This container view is being used to show an `UIPageViewController` and its various pages.
The view containing the container view also contains a navigation bar at the top of the page - which has the Page Control item in it.

This is the arrangement:  [image: Screenshot]

When it runs, I can swipe between the green and blue view controllers, and the navigation bar doesn't move.  How do I update the Page Control to show which page I am on?

Comment: please add your current code

Comment: refer this tutorial https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UIPageViewControllerDataSource

```
func presentationCount(for: UIPageViewController)
func presentationIndex(for: UIPageViewController)
```